# Deploying Angular 2 application into AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am now developing a front-end application using angular 2. This id for communicating with another micro services deploying in cloud. In this Angular 2 application I am not using database interaction.

I need to deploy this Angular 2 application in elastic beanstalk (AWS PaaS). What are the important procedure that I need to follow for deploying into cloud? I am new to angular framework and cloud platforms. How can I deploy my Angular 2 application into AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you need exactly to elastic beanstalk or you need just deploy to AWS using any suggested solutions?

If second - simplest way is to deploy Angular2 to S3 bucket, configured to serve static files:

- Go to S3
- Create new bucket
- Open bucket
- Go to "Properties" tab
  [image]
- Select "Static website hosting"
  [image]
- Check "Use this bucket to host a website" and provide "index.html" for both index and error pages
  [image]
- Build solutions using "ng build"
- Copy build results from "build" folder into this bucket
- Navigate to links, displayed in "Static website hosting" section

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. Actually my angular 2 is not static web site. It will communicate with microservices within the same amazon cloud. Angular make ReST API calls to my spring boot microservice application. When I exploring i found that elastic beanstalk is the platform as service from AWS. Thats why I searching elastic beanstalk deployment tutorials. Can you just tell why that platform is not suitable for my angular 2 deployment? What is the proper deployment method in AWS for my angular 2 application,since it will communicate with my microservices.

Comment: If you only call REST from your SPA - you can easy use S3. If you have server-side generated pages - you need use other services. Please check - if you build classic Angular2 appication - you can host it on S3 and make requests to any REST services. It works.

Comment: Yes sir. Only ReST call to my spring boot microservice will call from angular 2. There is no other back-end database related operation. Json data will come from microservices. Angular will only showing and send POST,PUT rest methods. But may I know why the AWS PaaS (Elastic Beanstalk ) is not suitable for my current requirement? Den Where I am using elastic beanstalk? Can you clarify that doubt also please? I have confusions still?

Comment: Serving static website S3 here is much cheeper. For elastic beanstalk you need to create EC2, for S3 you do not need it. Also you have other benefits here like cloudfront on top of S3 to support CDN for your distribution

Comment: But why I need to create EC2 for beanstalk? Elastic Beanstalk itself is a platform for deploying, don't need to take  care it's infrastructure.This why I understood. Can you help me to understand this concept properly, Since I am new to cloud. Please correct my way of exploration please?

Comment: Beanstalk here only constructor which allow you to provision predegined environment fast using some wizard. But on the core - it creates instances, balancers, db instances, etc. So you will pay for created infrastructure

Comment: Ok sir, I understood.Thank you for your guidance and spending time with me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's got something to do with the aws-sdk imported requiring a node runtime environment to execute properly. So the EBS machine and EC2 instances work for that specific use case as hosting a SPA via s3 does not have a nodejs runtime environment.