# How to create AWS Elastic Beanstalk for Angular 4 App?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to create AWS Elastic Beanstalk app for Angular 4 app.

What i did.

1. I created a eb.zip contains with angular **dist** folder with `package.json` because AWS Elastic Beanstalk nodejs platform need a package.json file in your app build. and I did not zipped the **dist** folder but I zipped the inner files and folders with package.json file because i read on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/angular/comments/76tgd8/anyone_deploying_to_aws_with_elastic_beanstalk/)
2. I created the AWS Elastic Beanstalk app with node.js platform with the app build that i created.

But the health status of AWS Elastic Beanstalk app is **Degraded**

the only warning I can see is :-

**Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Initialization completed 56 seconds ago and took 2 minutes. Impaired services on all instances.**

What i did wrong?

Comment: Your API may need to be released on EB but the angular client app itself may be better released serverless on cloud front

Comment: Check the answers for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180449/deploying-angular-2-application-into-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: @Nikhil I know how to deploy angular app but I need exactly to elastic beanstalk.